# Why does multiple comparison problems only occur with tests run on one set of data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

As [this paper](http://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/Abdi-Bonferroni2007-pretty.pdf) describes, the probability of committing a type 1 error increases with more hypothesis tests on the same data, such that if we have a test-wise alpha for each hypothesis test, the probability of committing a type 1 error is: 
$1 - (1-\alpha)^C$, if we have a family of C tests.

My only question is: why does this logic apply only to running a family of tests on the *same* data? Why doesn't it apply to hypothesis testing more generally on *any* series of datasets?

(I assume the answer to this is that tests on the same data might be similar, and thus the chances noticing a rare event happening goes up with multiple tests.)

What if we can reasonably conclude that the tests on the same dataset are independent? Is a correction like the [Bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) then too harsh?

Comment: The issue in multiple comparisons lies in making multiple *decisions* from the same data, not in having multiple sets of data.  But it's still a valid question.  For instance, you might ask whether a professional statistician ought to apply multiple-comparison corrections to account for all the decisions she helps make during her entire career, or whether a government ought to account for all the statistical decisions it might have to make during its tenure, *etc.*

Comment: maybe this can help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164181/family-wise-error-boundary-does-re-using-data-sets-on-different-studies-of-inde/164232#164232

Answer (score 2):

The paper's implication is incorrect--the problem of multiple testing applies any time you conduct more than one test, regardless of whether the tests were conducted on the "same data." If you conduct one test at .05, there's a .05 chance of Type I error under the null. If you conduct another test using a completely different set of data from a completely different set of subjects, the probability of Type I error in at least one of the two tests under the null is .05 + .05 - .05*.05 = .0975.